# can't process webhook received from shopping cart

Tags: php, webhooks

When someone places an order via my 3rd party shopping cart, the shopping cart POSTs a JSON encoded string of data about the sale to a receiving page on my website. My receiving page needs to decode the POST, extract the product id(s) of the product(s) sold, and update the status in the MySQL database.

This is the php code on my page that receives the POST:

```
$notification = $_POST;
if($notification == 'success'){
$order = json_decode($notification['order']);
$items = $order['items'];
foreach ( $items as $item ){
    $sql = "UPDATE posters SET stock_status='Sold' WHERE cartloom_ref = {$item['pid']}";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
}else{
header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
}
```

Here’s a cut-down version of the content of the actual POST:

```
order = {
    "items": [
        {
            "pid": "000004567",
            "item_id": "0001234545",
            "qty": "1",
            "title": "Widget2",
        }
    ],
    "subscribed": 1
}
```

So I want to match the product ID (“pid”) of the item that’s been sold (4567) with the “cartloom_ref” field in my db (4567), and change the record in my db from ’For Sale’ to ’Sold’.

I’ve had the POST sent to a third party (webhook.site) and it works fine. I’ve manually sent a POST to my receiving url and it works fine. So I’m stuck as to why it’s not working. It’s a basic Windows shared server.
If anyone can help, would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a `var_dump()` of `$items`? for `$order` too, but I'm assuming you're receiving it correctly till `$items`...

Comment: `$notification = $_POST` and than `$notification == 'success'` will always lead to false

Comment: Also you say that your own `cartloom_ref` is `4567`, but `$item['pid']` is padded with zeros, so it will not match unless you trim these zeros. Please note that your SQL is open to SQL Injection

Comment: You also not giving `$notifications` something specific to be filled by `$_POST` superglobal, so you'll never gonna read that `'success'` from the superglobal

Comment: Also your `$item` is going to be an object, not an array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to read a string from a given array in your `if` statement, `$_POST` superglobal will always give you an array, so if you try to read a string like `'success'` directly from the `$_POST` superglobal to condition a `if` statement, you'll never have a `true` response, so you may consider this:

```
$order = json_decode($_POST['order']);

if($order){
    $items = $order->items;
    foreach($items as $item){
        // I'll fix your query too because it's open to sql injection, you can use prepared statements:
        $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE posters SET stock_status='Sold' WHERE cartloom_ref = ?");
        $statement->bind_param("s", $item->pid);
        $statement->execute();
    }
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
}
```

Comment: So I tried this after amending to take into account the leading zeros:
 $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE posters SET stock_status='Sold' WHERE cartloom_ref = ?");
$pid_without_zeros = ltrim($item['pid'], '0'); 
$statement->bind_param("s", $pid_without_zeros);
$statement->execute();
But not db is not getting updated. Any suggestions? (Apologies, I have limited experience here.) Thanks

Comment: Usually you don't need to take care of the zeros, because normally if they placed on the left, MySQL doesn't take them into account, it will insert just the value `4567` for example of a given `000004567` string. As my concern the code is correct, should work as expected, try to debug the query, and the $items, or other variables to check if all the data is in there. you can change the `$statemente->execute();` to `        if (!$statement->execute()) {
            echo "Error: " . $conn->error;
        }` And see what's going on in case of any errors.

Comment: Thank you. Still can't get to work. But will mark answer as most helpful in to find a solution.

Comment: You can try with your own SLQ query to check if it works for you instead of using prepared statements.